# Get a complete a tag and not only the href attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am going through a string `container` to get all a tags it contains.

```
var links = container.find("a");            
links.each(function(i, txt){
   alert(txt); //shows http://some.com instead of <a href="http://some.com">some</a>
});
```

Any idea about how to solve this one? Thanks

Comment: alert() is not a debugging tool, try the console instead.

Comment: Or if you just have to use alerts, `alert(txt.outerHTML);`

Comment: Even better than console, step into the code with a debugger.

Comment: That's only because you're using `alert` to debug. Using `console.log` will show that `txt` is actually the real element ([demo](http://jsbin.com/udijaq/1/)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this -

```
alert(this.outerHTML);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `alert` the `toString` method prints the href.  Use the `outHTML` property to view what you want.

```
alert(text.outerHTML);
```